# Java - How to hide JButton by pressing another JButton?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton, jlabel

I need to write a simple program:

1. Three buttons
   GEN - which generate me a number
   HEX - which calculate my number to a hexadecimal number
   DEC - which calculate my number to a decimal number
2. JLabel
   It displays the number.

DEC button should hide when my number is DECIMAL and HEX button should hide when my number is HEXADECIMAL.

When I generate for example third number, it has to generate the HEXADECIMAL number when the prevoius generated number was also HEXADECIMAL.

Here is what I've done already:

GUI

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Okno {

    private JFrame okno;
    private JButton DecButt, HexButt, GenerujButt;
    private JLabel label_num;



    public JButton getDecButt() {
        return DecButt;
    }
    public void setDecButt(JButton decButt) {
        DecButt = decButt;
    }
    public JButton getHexButt() {
        return HexButt;
    }
    public JLabel getLabel_num() {
        return label_num;
    }



    public void createGUI() {
        okno = new JFrame("Okienko");
        okno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        okno.setSize(400, 300);
        okno.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


        //rzytowanie liczby na String zeby wyswietlic
        label_num = new JLabel();
        okno.add(label_num);

        //przyciski
        DecButt = new JButton("DEC");
        okno.add(DecButt);
        HexButt = new JButton("HEX");
        okno.add(HexButt);
        GenerujButt = new JButton("Generuj");
        okno.add(GenerujButt);


        ButtonAction przycisk;
        przycisk = new ButtonAction();

        //sluchacze do przyciskow
        DecButt.addActionListener(przycisk);
        HexButt.addActionListener(przycisk);
        GenerujButt.addActionListener(przycisk);


        okno.setVisible(true);

    }//createGUI

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {//klasa anonimowa - bo chcemy jej uzyc tylko raz

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Okno application = new Okno();
                    application.createGUI();
            }
        });//klasa anonimowa

    }


}//class
```

and the ActionListeners + generate number code and HEX, DEC calculators

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JLabel;



public class ButtonAction extends Okno implements ActionListener{

    private int dec;
    private String hex;

    public void setDec(int dec) {
        this.dec = dec;
    }
    public int getDec() {
        return dec;
    }

    public void setHex(String hex) {
        this.hex = hex;
    }
    public String getHex() {
        return hex;
    }

    public int generateNum() {

        Random r = new Random();
        int number = r.nextInt(1000);
        return number;
    }

    public static int hex2decimal(String decimal) {
        String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        decimal = decimal.toUpperCase();
        int val = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < decimal.length(); i++) {
            char c = decimal.charAt(i);
            int d = digits.indexOf(c);
            val = 16*val + d;
        }
        return val;
    }
    // precondition:  d is a nonnegative integer
    public static String decimal2hex(int d) {
        String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        if (d == 0) return "0";
        String hex = "";
        while (d > 0) {
            int digit = d % 16;
            hex = digits.charAt(digit) + hex;
            d = d / 16;
        }
        return hex;
    }





    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(arg0.getActionCommand() == "DEC")
        {
            setDec(hex2decimal(getHex()));
            System.out.println(getDec());
        }
        else if(arg0.getActionCommand() == "HEX")
        {
            setHex(decimal2hex(getDec()));
            System.out.println(getHex());
        }
        else if(arg0.getActionCommand() == "Generuj")
        {
            setDec(generateNum());
            System.out.println(getDec());
            //getDecButt().setVisible(false);**********HERE is NullPointerExceprion
        }

    }//actionperformed

}//class
```

I have nullpointerexception in ActionPerformed. Could someone tell me why ?

Comment: Hello!

The odds of someone answering your question will be greatly improved, if you only provide the code related to the question.

This is called the minimum verifiable example, and you can read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press a button, in the `ActionListener`, tell the button to be disabled, using `buttonObject.setEnabled(false)`

How your `ActionListener` is currently set up, the easiest way to solve it is to expose `JButton` to the rest of the package (though, that isn't really... recommended).

However, you could always add `ActionListener` programmatically inside the GUI class using this and an anonymous class (since doing so allows you to keep the `JButton` private):

```
buttonName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        buttonName.setEnabled(false);
        // Whatever other stuff you want to do.
    }
});
```

To deal with the display, simply create a `private` method which you call in each of the `ActionListener` anonymous classes.

Comment: It is almost OK, but now I need to change the generated number to the hexadecimal, so i need to create another 'ActionListener' on my HEX button... Then I get 0 on every hexadecimal change. I think that I can't create 'new ActionListener' on every button.

Comment: `I think that I can't create 'new ActionListener' on every button.` - did you try it?

Comment: [`JButton#disable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#disable--) has been deprecated since Java 1.1!!  You should be using `setEnabled` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer Dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

> DEC button should hide when my number is DECIMAL and HEX button should hide when my number is HEXADECIMAL.

I'm not sure I know why you should bother.  Instead, you could add the buttons to a `ButtonGroup` so that only one button can be "selected" at a time, used in combination of `JToggleButton` or `JRadioButton` you would also get the visual cue as to which button was selected

See [How to Use the ButtonGroup Component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details